# How to add dynamic id to text boxes and fetch its value?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to fetch value of each textbox keyup event inside for loop.And after the series of text boxes are created, I want to call keyup event, which fetch the value entered in each text box

what i have tried

```
script for assigning dynamic id

<textarea type="text" name="add'+ $i +'" id="add'+ $i +'"
value="" class="form-control" onkeyup="callans()" ></textarea> <br/>

function callans() {
for( var i=0; i<8; i++) 
   //i<9 because that's the maximum number of text 
  //fields to be created is 8.     
    {        




<textarea type="text" name="add'+ $i +'" id="add'+ $i +'"
value="" class="form-control" onkeyup="callans()" ></textarea> 

  var elements = document.getElementById("add'+ $i +'").value;

       alert(elements); 


    }
}
```

Is there a way only create the id's dynamically and append it in the input area?

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Show what you have tried and where you are stuck. When practical post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You do not need to use ID attributes - there are much cleaner and easier methods ~ querySelector, parent/child/sibling selectors etc - The ID plays no part in the data transmission or server side processing anyway

Answer (score 0):

Without using ID attributes you can very easily identify elements in the DOM by inspecting the `event` - in your case you are interested in the `keyup` event and to make life easier by using a `delegated event listener` bound to the input elements common parent we can obtain the values like so:

(vanilla js mainly )

```js
for( var i=0; i<8; i++){        
    $('#addition').append('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="add" />');
}

// delegated event listener bound to the parent container but processing only `INPUT` elements of type `text`
document.querySelector('#addition').addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
  if( e.target.tagName=='INPUT' && e.target.type=='text' ){
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='addition'></div>
```